# Why Solr Deletes documents when only Update is executed?

Tags: json, solr

I am inserting 677 JSON documents into Solr. After update is done when I check the total number of documents in Solr, it shows me following values:

[image]

`Num Docs: 676`
`Max Doc: 677`
`Deleted Docs: 1`

My question is, why Solr is deleting 1 document when all I have done is `post -c core *.json` in it.

I am using Solr version - 6.5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you have a duplicate document (or a duplicate key) in your json file.

I wrote this because Solr is based on the Lucene Java search library.

And Lucene, when found a duplicate document (which means a duplicate key) does not really update the document in the indexes but instead, behind the scenes, deletes and inserts a new document for each update.

[Lucene 6.5.0 - Class IndexWriter](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_5_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriter.html)

> [...] In either case, documents are added with addDocument and removed with
>   deleteDocuments(Term...) or deleteDocuments(Query...). **A document can
>   be updated with updateDocument (which just deletes and then adds the
>   entire document)**.

Comment: So, it means when we `post` a document, Solr first deletes it and then insert it. How, can that be possible, if document is being added in Solr for first time ?

Comment: I was misled by your incipit  "_I am updated/posted 677 JSON documents into Solr._". Probably you have a duplicate record (or a duplicate key) in your json file.

Comment: Sorry! My fault, I didn't posted my question correctly. Actually I am inserting 677 documents. If duplicate key is the case then I have to check for that. By the way I have updated my question.

Comment: Had you time to double check it?

Comment: Yes, I checked it ! Duplicate key was causing the problem.

Comment: I'm glad you found my answer useful :)